# Do methods always have to be called by an object or a class? (Java)

Tags: java, methods

You can call a method using myClass.myMethod() if its a static method. If its not static, you can call using myObject.myMethod() or just myMethod(). is there any other way to call it? and are there different circumstances where you can use an object to call it and call it without an object.

Comment: Note that you can also call a static method like `myMethod()` when you're "inside" the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JVM has 4 bytecodes for calling methods:

1. `invokestatic` for calling static methods (obviously)
2. `invokeinterface` for calling methods on interfaces (I don't know why they need a special bytecode, but they have one)
3. `invokespecial` for calling constructors and superclass methods
4. `invokevirtual` for calling all other methods

Comment: And now in Java 7 there is invokedynamic for calling methods not belonging to a class : )

Answer (score 3):

You may call a method indirectly [using reflection](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0031.html):

```
aClass  = lineInput("Class: ");
aMethod = lineInput("Method: ");

// get the Class
Class thisClass = Class.forName(aClass);

// get an instance
Object iClass = thisClass.newInstance();

// get the method
Method thisMethod = thisClass.getDeclaredMethod(aMethod, params);

// call the method
System.out.println(thisMethod.invoke(iClass, paramsObj).toString());
```

Comment: isn't reflection a way of calling a method from an object or a class?

Comment: You are indeed calling it through an object, but that's always an object of type `Method`, not `MyClass`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have methods without them belong to a class.  You have listed the two kinds:

- **static** which belong to the class instance (only one)
- and non-static which belongs to the individual object (one pr new).

Comment: _"static which belong to the class instance"_? Perhaps you meant it correct, but I wouldn't use the word "instance" in there. An instance is what you get after you use `new ...`.

Comment: @Bart, a class is an object too.

Comment: Sorry, I'm missing your point. Perhaps you're also missing mine? The official [Java tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) say that `int id;` is an **instance variable** , and they call `static int numberOfBicycles = 0;` a **class variable** . That is why I wouldn't use the word "instance" when you're explaining non-static methods (or variables).

Comment: "individual object" is better called "individual instance", IMO.

Answer (score 1):

Here are all (standard) cases, how you can call a method:

```
public class MyClass {
    static public void myClassMethod(){};
    public void myInstanceMethod(){};

    void foo(){
        //inside the same class definition, you can call its methods by name alone
        myClassMethod();
        myInstanceMethod();
    }
    static void bar(){
        myClassMethod();
        //myInstatnceMethod(); //wrong - you can't call instance method without instance
    } 
}
```

In other classes, you have to be more explicit

```
class OtherClass {
    public void baz(){
        MyClass.myClassMethod();
        (new MyClass()).myInstanceMethod();
    }
}
```

BUT from Java5.0 there is another way to call static methods (and reference static attributes) - with static import:

```
import static org.example.MyClass.myClassMethod;
import static java.lang.Math.*;    

class OtherClass {
    public void baz(){
         myClassMethod();
         System.out.println(floor(PI));
    }
}
```

Of course you can use reflection, but even with reflection if you want to call an instance method, you have to provide object of appropriate type.

Answer (score 0):

If you start a Java application with `java ... Foo`, the `Foo.main` Method is started from "outside" (at least you don't explicitly call it). Then there are indirect ways, e.g. reflection or when method calls are triggered by initialization:

```
class Foo {
   static int answer = deepThought();
   static int deepThought() { return 42; }
}
```

If you use the class `Foo` the first time, `answer` will have the value 42, even though nobody explicitly called `deepThought()`.

There are methods which are called "magically", e.g. `finalize()`, `readObject()`, `writeObject()` or `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.uncaughtException()`, where it is not really transparent where the call really came from.

Answer (score 0):

There are no other cases, and in fact they are both the same case. You have to call with an object. If the method is static the object can be the class.